# Has anyone been successful at capturing a triggered send name to a data extension field as a default in the data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, triggered-send

Has anyone been successful at capturing a triggered send name to a data extension field by setting this to an ampscript variable. Imagine having 40+ different triggered sends that are tied to SOAP API calls that occur from a proprietary business application. This application was written years ago and is still in service. Requesting the app dev team to add a custom value to get passed to a custom field for each of the API calls to uniquely identified which record is associated with which triggered Send in the data extension is going to take significant time to get this type of project moved up as a priority on their project list and for them to recompile/build the application. I had thoughts that there must be an easier way to accomplish identification records by triggered send being added in a data extension. (Usually if we mapped only one data extension per triggered send that would make things easier but it would be consuming for 40+ triggers not to mention that if the data for all 40+ triggers were already being sent to one data extension for years...it would muddy the waters if queries had to be run on multiple data extension to get out the data instead of just one for all the triggers.)

We know that data extensions have the unique ability to self capture the date timestamp for a record when it is added by selecting the option to capture the current timestamp. Is it also possible that such functionality to be embedded into a data extension when that data extension is a Triggered Send Data Extension? If so, has anyone had any success with performing such as simple capture to a data extension without having to force feed a hard coded value as part of the API call to the Triggered Send definition.

Answer (score 0):

Why not hard code the TSD Name in an AMPScript variable in your email and utilize the [**Send Log**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/) to record it?

Only issue would be that TSD Name would be in the Send Log and not in your Triggered Send DE.  Depending on how you wanted to use this information, a separate [**Query Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) to join them together into a new DE, wouldn't be too difficult.

You can't really use a Query Activity tp update TSD Templated DEs because there's no primary key, so the results would need to be in another DE.

Comment: This would not serve our needs. We have a master data extension called 'Customers' which houses about 54 different fields and 40 Triggered sends point to that data extension. We want to be able to uniquely identify all 54 fields of each row from it's source (TriggerSend Name). There are about 3.5 million records. We also have a situation where even though we can query and join the 'Customers' data to a send data view and filter on s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey, joining on emailAddress/subscriberkey is indeterminant since email addresses can have multiple subscriberkeys as no primary key exist.

Comment: That's the main reason I give TSDs their own DE. That way you can have a defaulted field contain the trigger name.

Comment: Couple this with also the fact that different api calls were modified at various points in time to send different fields we can't cleanly/confidently be sure of what fields belong to which triggers sends since some api calls may send the same 1:1 exact match of fields and others send a variation of shared and non-shared fields. It would be ideal of we could embed something like %%externalKey_%% or RequestParameter("externalKey") in a text field of a data extension pulling in any relevant value. It would seem logical to make this work through some Lookup function but nothing i've tried works.

Comment: I would agree on the TSDs having their own DE but having 40 of them is a big onerous process recreating them all and preserving all the external keys is a process to create, rename old, give new the existing extkey and delete old. No one has offered a fix to make it easier to just point to new data extensions using the same trigger. You have to recreate the triggers themselves.

Comment: I still think you may be able to join them together into a new DE with a query if you write the trigger name to the sendlog.

Comment: Also the tsd key is in the _job system data view